# JavaFx - Wrap content text in alert dialg

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

How to set wraptext option in an alert dialog box? I tried to do this:

```
Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
alert.getButtonTypes().set(0, ButtonType.NO);
alert.getButtonTypes().set(1, ButtonType.YES);
alert.getDialogPane().getStylesheets().add("/styles/style.css");
alert.setGraphic(new ImageView(getIcon(icon)));
Label lb = (Label) alert.getDialogPane().getChildren().get(1);
lb.setWrapText(true); //Attempt to set wrapText option
alert.setTitle(title);
alert.setHeaderText(header);
alert.setContentText(content);
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Create a new label instead, and set it as the content for the DialogPane:

```
Label label = new Label("Label with\nText that should be wrapped.");
label.setWrapText(true);
alert.getDialogPane().setContent(lb);
```

Remember that `WrapText` only wraps on line ending chars (\n), not automatically.

If you want to wrap automatically, use a `Text` element instead and set the `WrappingWidth` property:

```
Text text = new Text("Very long text that should be wrapped in the dialog");
text.setWrappingWidth(100);
alert.getDialogPane().setContent(text);
```

Answer (score 2):

I find it frustrating to have to type all that, and using Text doesn't provide any padding, so I use something like this from a utility lib:

```
public static Alert createAlert(Alert.AlertType type, String message) {
    Alert alert = new Alert(type);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(message);
    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i += 200) {
        sb.insert(i, "\n");
    }

    Label t = new Label(sb.toString());
    alert.getDialogPane().setContent(t);
    return alert;
}
```

Which makes it more reasonable to use:

```
Alert alert = FxUtil.createAlert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, ex.getMessage());
alert.show();
```

It'd be nice if it did something like this automatically... cutting off messages of this nature is pretty useless:

*I'm getting an error message. It says: "Parsing error on line number..." Any idea what went wrong?*